Chrome driver version (125) can't find the chromedriver.exe
I have downloaded the latest Chrome version from link https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable for Windows 64 (125.0.6422.60). But after downloading, I am unable to get the chromedriver.exe file.
I am getting a lot of files, as attached in the screenshot:

What needs to be done after this? I am unable to understand what path to give in the selenium code (System.setProperty).
I tried giving paths ***\\chrome-win64\\chrome-win64\\Google Chrome for Testing.exe OR ***\\chrome-win64\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe, but, it's not working.

The link you provided https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable is correct. The clue is that you downloaded chrome-win64.zip file instead of chromedriver-win64.zip file, where you can find the chromedriver.exe file.


Try this link to download chromedriver.exe for version 125:
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/125.0.6422.60/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
You should be able to download a compressed file which should have 2 files as below.


https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable now provides Chromedriver for Chrome v126, however I have Chrome v125 and it says up-to-date. So I'm unable to upgrade Chrome to v126 and unable to get Chromedriver for v125. This link shared by @Shawn is hence very helpful.

Try this  to download chromedriver.exe
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/125.0.6422.60/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
